# PHP rand only works once

Tags: php

I got the following index.php on [a testsite](http://sithu.net/testinggrounds/):

```
<?php
    $r = rand(1, 1000);
    $mtr=mt_rand(1, 1000);
    echo "rand(1, 1000): " . $r;
    echo "<br>mt_rand(1, 1000): " . $mtr;
?>
```

For some reason i can only get it to run once when the page loads, giving me two random numbers, as it should, and maybe once more if i reload the page with F5. But then it refuses to produce any random numbers until a couple minutes have passed.

I feel I am missing something obvious. The server is hosted by MissHosting.se, and runs php5.6. Customer support insists it is a code issue. I will be glad to provide any further information on request.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Call the side like that `http://sithu.net/testinggrounds/?a` `http://sithu.net/testinggrounds/?ab` and so on, there is a page cache at work.

Comment: Look at the headers from the page: `X-Cache:HIT
X-Cache-Hits:1
X-Varnish:5816388 5816386`

Comment: `echo {rand(1, 1000)}: " . $r;` - You need to wrap it round `{}` since echo doesn't know if its a function or a string.

Comment: @KDOT The result is in `$r` the part before is only a description of what was called to get the `$r` value.

Comment: The OP is actually trying to print the function names onto the page, followed by the `$r` and `$mtr` variables. Give them some credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the fact that your server employs some kind of cache. To rule out client side caching (i.e. browser cache) I requested the page several times with curl, which does not do any caching. So it is a server cache.

Now if we look at the headers with curl:

```
~$ curl http://sithu.net/testinggrounds/ -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 17 Feb 2017 16:09:36 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Varnish: 6817501 6109691
Age: 9
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 1
Accept-Ranges:  none
Connection: keep-alive
```

The headers clearly indicate that the server does caching and we have hit the server cache (`X-Cache: HIT` and `X-Cache-Hits: 1`). So the next step would be to find out how/where you can change your server caching mechanism.

The `X-Varnish` header indicates that your server/hoster is using the [Varnish HTTP Cache](http://www.varnish-cache.org/) to do the caching.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that out! I'll get back to you.

Comment: YES! xVarnish was the culprit. I turned it off, and now it works as far as i can tell!

Comment: Glad it got the problem solved. :) Please do not forget to upvote the answer, if it was helpful.